# Semantic UI coupled modals not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I have an issue with Semantic UI. I'm attempting to use multiple modals, but upon pressing the Approve button on the first modal, the second one flashes for a very brief moment and they both close afterwards (tested in Firefox and Chrome). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

My code:

```
<body>
    <div class="ui coupled first modal">
      <div class="header">Header 1</div>
      <div class="actions">
        <div class="ui approve button">Approve</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui coupled second modal">
      <div class="header">Header 2</div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $('.coupled.modal').modal({
            allowMultiple: true
        });

        $('.second.modal').modal('attach events', '.first.modal .button');

        $('.first.modal').modal({
            transition: 'fade up'
        }).modal('show');
    </script>
</body>
```

Here's my JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tm95bwpf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the documentation on modal settings](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html#/definition)

> Close actions are applied by default to all button actions, in
>   addition an onApprove or onDeny callback will fire if the elements
>   match either selector.
>
> approve  : '.positive, .approve, .ok', deny     : '.negative, .deny,
>   .cancel'

When you had 'approve' as your class, it was causing the modals to close because it would fire the onApprove event.

Answer (score 1):

Changing

```
<div class="ui approve button">Approve</div>
```

to

```
<div class="ui primary button">Approve</div>
```

fixes the issue.